# Blocking read on pipe after fork when using pipe instead of pipe2

Tags: linux, multithreading, fork

The following code sometimes blocks on `read(fds[0]...)` in `spawn()` when forking a specific process in `spawn()`.

```cc
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void spawn()
{
  static std::mutex m;
  static std::atomic<int> displayNumber{30000};

  std::string display{":" + std::to_string(displayNumber++)};
  const char* const args[] = {"NullXServer", display.c_str(), nullptr};

  int fds[2];

  m.lock();
  pipe(fds);
  int oldFlags = fcntl(fds[0], F_GETFD);
  fcntl(fds[0], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
  oldFlags = fcntl(fds[1], F_GETFD);
  fcntl(fds[1], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
  m.unlock();

  if (vfork() == 0) {
    execvp("NullXServer", const_cast<char**>(args));
    _exit(0);
  }

  close(fds[1]);
  int i;
  read(fds[0], &i, sizeof(int));
  close(fds[0]);
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    threads.emplace_back(spawn);
  }

  for (auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Note; creating the pipe here is sort of useless. It is only done to demonstrate the deadlock. The `read(fds[0], ...)` in `spawn()` should never block. All write-ends of the pipe have been closed once `read` is called, which should result in `read` returning immediately. The write-end of the pipe in the parent process is closed explicitly, and the write-end in the child process is closed implicitly due to the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set on the file descriptor, which will close the file descriptor as soon as `execvp` succeeds (which it always does in this case).

The problem here is that I do see `read()` blocking once in a while.

Replacing all of:

```cc
m.lock();
pipe(fds);
int oldFlags = fcntl(fds[0], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[0], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
oldFlags = fcntl(fds[1], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[1], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
m.unlock();
```

by:

```cc
pipe2(fds, O_CLOEXEC);
```

fixes the blocking read, even though both pieces of code should at least result in `FD_CLOEXEC` being set atomically for the pipe file descriptors.

Unfortunately, I do not have `pipe2` available on all platforms we deploy on.

Can anybody shed some light on why the `read` would block in the above code using the `pipe` approach?

Some more observations:

- Extending the mutex lock to cover the `vfork()` block solves the blocking read.
- Not one system call fails.
- Using `fork()` instead of `vfork()` exhibits the same behavior.
- The process that is spawned matters. In this case, a 'null' X server process is spawned on a specific display. Forking 'ls' here for example does not block, or the chances that a block occurs are significantly lower, I am not sure.
- Reproduceable on Linux 2.6.18 up to 4.12.8, so this is not some kind of Linux kernel issue I assume.
- Reproduceable using both GCC 4.8.2 and GCC 7.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is, that *after* you create the pipe here

```
// Thread A
int fds[2];

m.lock();
pipe(fds);
```

another thread might just `vfork()` and exec

```
// Thread B
if (vfork() == 0) {
   execvp("NullXServer", const_cast<char**>(args));
   _exit(0);
}
```

right before you set the file descriptor flags:

```
// Thread A again...
int oldFlags = fcntl(fds[0], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[0], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
oldFlags = fcntl(fds[1], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[1], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
m.unlock();
```

so the resulting child process of B will inherit the file descriptors created by thread A.

It should help to extend the mutex to include the `vfork()/execvp()` to migitate this effect.

```
m.lock();
pipe(fds);
int oldFlags = fcntl(fds[0], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[0], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);
oldFlags = fcntl(fds[1], F_GETFD);
fcntl(fds[1], F_SETFD, oldFlags | FD_CLOEXEC);

if (vfork() == 0) {
    execvp("NullXServer", const_cast<char**>(args));
    _exit(0);
}
m.unlock();
```

Comment: Thanks, of course. Feeling a bit ashamed now :) Of course the mutex here does not guarantee that only one thread will actually be running while setting the file descriptor flags, which is sort of the impression I had for some reason.

Comment: @TonvandenHeuvel No need to be embarrassed, concurrent code is just too often a pita to think through properly ;)